# Insert multiple child nodes with same structure into the given parent node

Tags: javascript, html

Let's say I have an html container:
  `<div id="container"></div>`
And I have this code for a `child`, which is supposed to be inserted into the `container`. A `child` has a complex structure - it has another tags in it:

```
<div class="child">
    <p>P element</p>
    <img src="img.png" alt="alt">
    <p>some other elem</p>
  </div>
```

To insert one `child` element to `container` from JS I doo the following:

```
var htmlCode = {
  child: '<div class="child"> <p>P element</p><img src="img.png" alt="alt"> <p>some other elem</p></div>'
}

function insertChild(){
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = htmlCode.child;
}

insertChild();
```

But how do I insert multiple `child` ? I need something like:

```
function insertMultipleChildren(childrenAmount) {
  // some magic to insert N children
}
```

Everything must be done with pure JS (no Jquery, etc)
Also: is there a chance to use non-minified html in pure JS ? Like in .jsx in React ?

A pen: https://codepen.io/t411tocreate/pen/dZwwby?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this ([working pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZaVVBm?editors=1010))

```
insertMultipleChildren(20);

function insertMultipleChildren(childrenAmount) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  for( var counter = 0; counter < childrenAmount; counter++ )
  {
    var div = document.createElement( "div" ); //create div
    container.appendChild( div ); //append div to container
    div.outerHTML = htmlCode.child; //set outerHTML 
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use for loop like :

```
function insertMultipleChildren(childrenAmount) {
   var container = document.getElementById("container");
   var result = "";

   for (var i = 0; i < childrenAmount; i++) {
       result += htmlCode.child;
   }

   container.innerHTML = result;
}
```

```js
var htmlCode = {
  child: '<div class="child"> <p>P element</p><img src="img.png" alt="alt"> <p>some other elem</p></div>'
}

function insertChild() {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  container.innerHTML = htmlCode.child;
}


function insertMultipleChildren(childrenAmount) {
  var container = document.getElementById("container");
  var result = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < childrenAmount; i++) {
      result += htmlCode.child;
  }

  container.innerHTML = result;
}

insertMultipleChildren(5);
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have at least three choices:

1. Since you're starting with a string, you could just build a string containing all the children as HTML, then do one assignment to `innerHTML`. (I would not recommend `+=` with `innerHTML`. Every time you read from `innerHTML`, the browser has to go through the DOM of the element and build up a string and every time you assign to it, it has to destroy those previous elements and build new ones. Lots of easily-avoidable work, although of course it frequently doesn't matter.)
2. Parse the string and repeatedly call `appendChild` on the parent with `cloneNode(true)` on the parsed result.
3. Repeatedly insert using `insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", ...)`.

More to explore:

- [DOM on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)
- [DOM specs](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR)
  Example of #1:

```js
var htmlCode = {
  child: '<div class="child"> <p>P element</p><img src="img.png" alt="alt"> <p>some other elem</p></div>'
};

var container = document.getElementById("container");
var str = "";
// 10 children
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  str += htmlCode.child;
}
container.innerHTML = str;
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Example of #2:

```js
var htmlCode = {
  child: '<div class="child"> <p>P element</p><img src="img.png" alt="alt"> <p>some other elem</p></div>'
};

// Cheap-and-dirty parsing
var div = document.createElement("div");
div.innerHTML = htmlCode.child;

var container = document.getElementById("container");
// Empty the container (if necessary)
while (container.lastChild) {
  container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
}
// 10 children
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  container.appendChild(div.firstChild.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```

Example of #3:

```js
var htmlCode = {
  child: '<div class="child"> <p>P element</p><img src="img.png" alt="alt"> <p>some other elem</p></div>'
};

var container = document.getElementById("container");
// Empty the container (if necessary)
while (container.lastChild) {
  container.removeChild(container.lastChild);
}
// 10 children
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  container.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", htmlCode.child);
}
```

```html
<div id="container"></div>
```